# Start Accumulating from the next month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data:

```
Month|Order|OrdersAcc
APR  |4    |4
MAY  |3    |7
```

What i need to is start accumulating from May instead of April meaning the result should be:

```
Month|Order|OrdersAcc
APR  |4    | NULL
MAY  |3    |4
JUN  |2    |7
JUL  |4    |9
```

Please assist with a query that can achieve this.

Let me simplify this. This is the query that does the Accumulation:

```
  SELECT        SUM(t2.OrdersAcc) AS OrdersAcc, t1.MONTH_sort2, t1.ActMonth

FROM            dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions AS t1 INNER JOIN

                             (SELECT        SUM(Orders) AS OrdersAcc, Region, MONTH_sort2

                               FROM            dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions

                               GROUP BY Region, MONTH_sort2, ActMonth) AS t2 ON t1.Region = t2.Region AND t1.MONTH_sort2 >= t2.MONTH_sort2

GROUP BY t1.Region, t1.MONTH_sort2, ActMonth
```

I am using the month_sort2 column because it has increment integers from 1 up until 12 with 1 representing April, 2 representing May and so on and so forth.
Figures from the 1st month (April) need to be shown in May and then from May they need to accumulate. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Sure, let's throw numbers to the air, and people will understand what I did. Right?

Comment: Imagine going to a mechanic. You come and say:  I have a car, it has doors and tires. How can I have a car like my friend Mike, it looks like a different car.

Comment: Any code which you have tired? BTW you can try with sum with case and in where clause have month < april

Comment: Please check the latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or above I'd recommend you look into windowed functions - particularly LEAD & LAG.

There's other ways to do this but it showcases the power of windowed functions and how to chain them together.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions
(   
    Month_Sort2 INT
   ,Orders INT
   ,Region NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions
VALUES (1,4,'Placeholder')
      ,(2,3,'Placeholder')
      ,(3,2,'Placeholder')
      ,(4,4,'Placeholder')
      ,(5,3,'Placeholder')
      ,(6,1,'Placeholder')
      ,(7,2,'Placeholder')
      ,(8,4,'Placeholder')
      ,(9,3,'Placeholder')
      ,(10,7,'Placeholder')
      ,(11,3,'Placeholder')
      ,(12,9,'Placeholder')


SELECT UPPER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(3),DATENAME(mm,DATEADD(mm,t.MonthID + 3,-1)))) AS Month
      ,t.Orders
      ,LAG(t.SumOrders) OVER (ORDER BY MonthID) AS OrdersAcc
FROM
     (
        SELECT o.Month_Sort2 AS MonthID
              ,o.Orders AS Orders
              ,SUM(o.Orders) OVER (ORDER BY o.Month_Sort2) AS SumOrders
        FROM dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions o
     ) t
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your suggestion, maybe give a small example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [month_row_id] INT
   ,[motnh] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[order] INT

);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([month_row_id], [motnh], [order])
VALUES (1, 'APR', 4)
      ,(2, 'MAY', 3)
      ,(3, 'JUN', 2)
      ,(4, 'JULY',4);

SELECT [motnh]
      ,[order]
      ,SUM([order]) OVER (ORDER BY [month_row_id] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - [order] AS [OrderAcc]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

The idea is to accumulating the values till current row but exclude the current row value with simple `-` operation.

Also, note that I have added a `month_row_id` column in order to have a way to order the rows in time as using month name is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```
SELECT        SUM(t2.OrdersAcc) AS OrdersAcc, t1.MONTH_sort2, t1.ActMonth

FROM            dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions AS t1 INNER JOIN

                             (SELECT        SUM(Orders) AS OrdersAcc, Region, MONTH_sort2

                               FROM            dbo.tbl_ME_OrderCompletions


                               GROUP BY Region, MONTH_sort2, ActMonth) AS t2 ON t1.MONTH_sort2 > t2.MONTH_sort2

GROUP t1.MONTH_sort2, ActMonth
```

All I had to do was change the Month_sort2 join from is equal to or greater than to greater than. thanks for your assistance

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? This might work, but it will become very inefficient with more rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify your question a bit. But from what I'm gathering, you're looking for:

```
; WITH t AS (
  SELECT 4 AS monthNum, 'APR' AS m, 4 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS monthNum, 'MAY' AS m, 3 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS monthNum, 'JUN' AS m, 2 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS monthNum, 'JUL' AS m, 4 AS t
)
SELECT s1.m,s1.t
    , SUM(s1.prevT) OVER (ORDER BY s1.monthNum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS totalT
FROM (
    SELECT t.monthNum, t.m, t.t
        , (LAG(t.t) OVER (ORDER BY t.monthNum)) AS prevT 
    FROM t
) s1
;
```

1) This only works on MS SQL Server 2012 or better.

2) You have to have a way to order your months. I've added a monthNum column to do this.

===================================================

For SQL 2008 and 2008R2:

```
; WITH t AS (
    SELECT 4 AS monthNum, 'APR' AS m, 4 AS t UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS monthNum, 'MAY' AS m, 3 AS t UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS monthNum, 'JUN' AS m, 2 AS t UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS monthNum, 'JUL' AS m, 4 AS t
)
SELECT t3.m, t3.t, NULLIF(t3.runningTotal, t3.t) AS nulledRunningTotal
FROM (
    SELECT t.monthNum, t.m, t.t
        , ( SELECT SUM(t2.t) FROM t t2 WHERE t2.monthNum <= t.monthNum ) AS runningTotal
    FROM t
) t3 ;
```

I think this may be the first time I've actually ever used a `NULLIF()`. So if you need to go pre-2008, you can change `NULLIF(t3.runningTotal,t3.t)` to `CASE WHEN t3.runningTotal<>t3.t THEN t3.runningTotal ELSE NULL END`.